# SQL: Is it possible to merge these two SQL statements into a single query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance, processing-efficiency

I am using MS SQL Server 2014 on Windows 7.

In the database I have a table named `Orders`, which looks like this:

```
OrderID | CustomerID | OrderDate | ...   
----------------------------------------
1028      90           2015-10-10   
...
2416      68           2016-02-12
```

I needed two things:

1. the total number of customers
2. the number of customers this year.

I am a beginner in SQL, but I managed to write 2 SQL statements in my app that seem to do the job:

For requirement #1

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) FROM Orders; // result = 74
```

For requirement #2:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '2016-01-01'; // result = 34
```

I would like to know if it's possible to merge/combine *somehow* the above 2 SQL statements into one single query...? Of course, I need both results: the total customers (74 in above case) and also the customers of this year (i.e. 34).

The database is a remote database, so any idea to speed-up the query performance is highly welcome :)

Comment: Why have you tagged mysql and sql-server-ce, if your question is about SQL Server 2014? I have removed them.

Comment: Hehe, mysql was a `suggested tag` and sql-server-ce was added by other user. Thanks for editing.

Comment: We have 2 answers (for the moment), see below. I tested both and both are working ok. Which one is **faster** or are they about the same speed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) as Total,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN OrderDate >= '2016-01-01' THEN CustomerID END) as Total_2016
FROM Orders;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine the data horizontally as in the previous answer or you can combine them vertically using a UNION, like this, if you think you need a tabular form:

```
SELECT 'Total Customers' As Description, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) As Number FROM Orders // total = 74   
Union ALL   
SELECT '2016 Customers' AS Description, COUNT(DISTINCT CustomerID) As Number FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate >= '2016-01-01'; // this_year = 34
```